# can I send any string in an XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this basic (I'm just begining with this) script

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if ( this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ) {
    modules = JSON.parse ( this.responseText );

    if ( modules.length != 0 ) {
        modsMenu = "<ul>";
        for (i in modules.mods) {
            mod = modules.mods [ i ];
            modsMenu +=
            "<li><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"getMenu( \'" + mod + "\' )\">" +
            mod + "</a></li>";
        }
        modsMenu += "</ul>"
        document.getElementById("menu_mods").innerHTML = modsMenu;
    }
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET", "dbase.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

now...

if my "url" is something like "file.ext" it works perfectly
but the destination web server is a device from mine which understands special requirements
for example: "dbr:disp,mods"
so, if I send

xmlhttp.open("GET", "dbase.txt", true);

it works
but if I send

xmlhttp.open("GET", "dbr:disp,mods", true);

it doesn't

but if I send the url directly from browser (for example http://192.168.1.10/dbr:disp,mods) it gets my web server

it means that is not an illegal url, is it?

but java script doesn't process it correctly

I've tried "dbr:disp", "dbr:3"...

which are legal characters for send?

or...

which is the way to send free strings after GET method?

any help?

thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried using the complete URL (e.g., "http://192.168.1.10/dbr:disp,mods")? I suspect that the colon in your special name is causing it to treat "dbr:" as the protocol and thus it is not expanding it to the full URL.

Comment: Excellent Jack.. it works!!
(now I only need to know from inside the javascript, the IP address which I am talking with.....do you know how?)

Comment: You can use the `window.location` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: I wil try. Thank you again. I really appreciate

Comment: it worked, but...
now I realize that the request send is: GET /192.168.1.10/dbr:disp,mods HTTP/1.1 
It's ok, I can the address out, but...not perfect solution :-)
thank you very much anyway

Comment: `window.location.origin` + ....